# Is the thought on this problem on LC circuits correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I have the following problem and I want to know if my thought is correct: In one $LC$ circuit, on which $C=4,0\mu F$, the maximum potential difference across the capacitor during the oscilations is $V_m=1,25V$ and the maxium current across the inductor is $I_m=50mA$.

$(a)$ Find the inductance of the inductor. My solution was: first we note that the charge on the capacitor satisfies the relation $q(t) = Q \cos (\omega_0 t + \phi)$ where $Q$ is the maximum charge. In that case, the current across the capacitor must be $q'(t)=-\omega_0Q \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi)$. The negative sign evidences that the charge is leaving the capacitor and flowing in the direction of the inductor. So this must be the same rate at which the charge flows through the inductor, so the current through the inductor must be $i(t) = \omega_0 Q \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi)$. In that case the maximum current must be $\omega_0 Q$. Since $Q = CV$, the maximum charge is obtained with the maximum potential, so $Q = CV_m$, in that case the maximum current is $I_m = \omega_0 CV_m$. Now I've used $\omega_0 = 1/\sqrt{LC}$, so that we have:

$$I_m = \frac{CV_m}{\sqrt{LC}}\Longrightarrow \sqrt{LC}=\frac{CV_m}{I_m}\Longrightarrow L=C\left(\frac{V_m}{I_m}\right)^2$$
Putting the values there I've found $L = 2500 \mu H$

$(b)$ Find the frequency of oscilations: My solution was to use $\omega_0 = 2\pi f$, so that we have $f = \omega_0 / 2\pi$, in that case we have:

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

And using $C=4,0\mu F$ and $L=2500 \mu H$ I've got $f = 10^4/(2\pi) \operatorname{Hz}$.

$(c)$ Find the time on which the charge on the capacitor goes from zero to the maximum. I've analyzed graphically, the time it takes for the charge to go from the maximum to the maximum again is the period $T$. The time it takes to reach $0$ is one fourth of the period. So, since the time for the carge to get from maximum to zero must be the same as getting from zero to maximum, the desired time is:

$$t = \frac{1}{4}T=\frac{1}{4f}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{LC}}{2}$$

And for this problem I've found $ t = (\pi \cdot 10^{-4}/2 )\operatorname{s}$ .

Now, is my thought correct in all three items? I'm preocupated because I didn't even thought about what happened to the phase. My thought was: "well, it's arbitrary, it will just have to do with where we start measuring $t$", but I'm not sure. Also, the manipulations in general, are they all correct?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's distill your question down to its conceptual essence:

*Given an LC circuit, the capacitance $C$, the maximum voltage $V_m$ and the maximum current $I_m$, can you find the inductance $L$.*

That's really all there is to it since, once you find $L$, you know the frequency and the period.

(By the way, in an LC circuit there is only one independent voltage and one independent current).

The answer is yes, you can find $L$.

Since you know the maximum voltage, you know the maximum energy stored by the capacitor and thus, you know the maximum energy stored by the inductor (there is no energy lost in an LC circuit).  Thus, you have the relation:

$\dfrac{CV^2_m}{2} = \dfrac{L I^2_m}{2}$

You can solve for L with this since you're given the other values and the rest follows.